# jQuery Mobile - Modifying lists and updating corners

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile list using the standard theme.

If I manipulate the DOM using jQuery and Remove the top LI or bottom LI(Rounded corners), How do I get it to round the corners again? Thanks!

Comment: please post some sample code.It helps better in getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all of the answers here are right, and it was my fault for not providing my markup. But for my problem it turned out that I was accessing my listview() with a descendant selector instead of an ID.

For example:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
```

I would then Append an LI to the DOM using jQuery. After appending an LI it seems that the listview data-role widget would un-initialize itself.

When accessing an id you can simply refresh. However when accessing a class or descendant it would error when doing the following:

```
var list = $('#message-listing ul');
list.listview('refresh');
```

Return Error:

```
Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
```

Solution:

```
var list = $('#message-listing ul');
list.listview();
list.listview('refresh');
```

Further reading:

Reference: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/wish-listview-refresh-would-go-away

Answer (score 2):

Live Examples:

- http://jsfiddle.net/B7nhA/2/ (the problem)
- http://jsfiddle.net/B7nhA/4/ (the solution)

JS

```
$('ul#listOfSheets li:first').remove(); // removes the first li
$('#listOfSheets').listview('refresh'); // refreshes the ul list
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="b">    
    <div>
        <ul id="listOfSheets" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li class="hidden"><a href="#" data-ajax="false">Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="hidden"><a href="#" data-ajax="false">Link 2</a></li>
            <li class="hidden"><a href="#" data-ajax="false">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div><!-- /content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

think you remove all LI-rounded corners, try getting the first and last LI via class/id and remove the rounded corners explicitly only for these two?